# Will Orchard 1.6.1 work with .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, .net-4.5, orchardcms-1.6

Has anyone tried converting Orchard to .NET 4.5? It's using MVC 4 but looks like the projects are targeted for .NET 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.6.1 does support 4.5, but I've not personally tried it. There was talk of dropping support for 4.0 in Orchard 1.7, but they decided not to.

> Support for 4.5 is already there and is not going anywhere. It is in
>   1.6 and it is in 1.7.

Source: [Orchard Workitem 19865](https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19865#CommentContainer9)

Comment: sweet! I'll try it out

Answer (score 1):

I have done a full conversion of projects in 1.6 to .net 4.5 with no problems. You should be fine